# How to display loading widget from jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a problem with the loading widget from jquery mobile. I use the version **1.4.3**.

I have following code, but I never see the loading widget.

```
function .......() {   
$.ajax({
  url: "https://.........../......./.........svc/..../" + ..........,
  type: 'GET',
  contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
  beforeSend: function() {
     $.mobile.loading("show", {
        text: "some text",
        textVisible: true,
        theme: "a",
        textonly: false,
        html: ""
     });
  },
  success: function (data) {
     return data.RetValue;
  },
  error: function () {
     return false;
  }
  });
}
```

I want that it shows the loading panel with a text below.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: when do you call that function? if you call it before page is shown, it won't be visible.

Comment: I call it in document on pagebeforecreate

Comment: Come on!!!!!! Tell me how to display a jquery Mobile popup and a loading pandel automatically in jquery!!!!!!!!!